# How to erase the transparent part of the image

Tags: html, css, transparency

I want to add this image in my website, but it look like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdcBc.png)

As you can see, this picture is transparent, but you can see grey and white boxes in background.

How can I delete the background boxes?

This is my code.

```css
.first-cloud{
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  position:relative;
  left: 60%;
}
```

```html
  <img class="first-cloud" src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/508/582/png-clipart-cloud-computing-drawing-cartoon-cloud-white-cloud-love-white.png" alt="cloud">
```

Comment: The image is ***not*** transparent. It just has a background of squares.

Comment: Image is definetly not transparent. Best bet would be to edit it and remove the background.

Comment: Your image does not have a transparent background.

Comment: Don't hotlink images from clipart websites. Just download them and include them in your own site.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out, the image that you are using is not transparent.

This is a security measure from the website you are [hotlinking](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotlinking) it from. If you instead go ahead and download the image from the website, you will get a transparent version.

To download the image, follow these steps:

1. Go to this link: https://www.pngegg.com/en/png-bzgkn
2. Press the green button that says "Download PNG for free"
3. Save it to your computer

Comment: If they'd just _download_ the clipart from that clip art site instead of hotlinking it, it _would_ be transparent, though.

Comment: That's true @Nyerguds. Changed my answer to instead include instructions for downloading that specific image. Your answer is excellent by the way.

Answer (score 0):

To make an image have a transparent background, download the free program [Gimp2](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) (alternative to Photoshop) and follow one of the tutorials on the web for creating a transparent background.

Note that .jpg files cannot have a transparent background - you must re-save the file as .png or .webp file format.

From Thomas Cokelaer's blog post of 2016:

**To create a transparent background:**

1. Open your image in Gimp2.
2. Select the area you want to make transparent.
   Select using the appropriate selection tool from the Tool window or the Tools – Selection Tools menu on the Layer window. I usually use the magic wand/fuzzy select (Select contiguous region) tool or the **Select regions by color** tool.
   Click in the region you want selected. Use shift-click to add more regions/colors.Tip: It’s easier if you zoom in (View – Zoom menu) to see finer details of exactly what you’re selecting.
3. In the Layer window (the one showing your image), select Layer – Transparency – Add Alpha Channel.If this is blanked out then it’s already done. This makes sure your image can store transparency data
4. Select Edit – Clear. This makes the selection transparent.
5. Save the file. Note: If you save it as a PNG file, be sure to select the ‘Save colour values from transparent pixels’ option in the Save as PNG dialog box.

References:

http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2016/09/gimp-how-to-make-a-transparent-background/

https://www.guidingtech.com/image-background-transparent-gimp/

Comment: If they'd just _download_ the clipart from that clip art site instead of hotlinking it, it _would_ be transparent, though.